# Have Javascript display some text onMouseOver

Tags: javascript

i have this line of code

```
<img src="1.png" id="friends" onMouseOver="document.writeln('We are 86');"</h2>
```

I want instead of remove everything else on the site, when i hover over it, to display a bit of text under it.
How would this be done?
Thanks

- Jesper

Comment: document.writeln will completely clear the document, so that's not the way to go.
Why not use an alt/title attribute with the image?

Answer (score 2):

You could either add a `title` attribute that most browsers will display automatically when you hover over the element without the need for any additional Javascript or you could use a library like [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/).

Comment: Yeah, but with title you have to hold it over for a second or two, i want to remove that..

Comment: Then use a library like tipsy.